# Is allocating a struct on the heap or having a struct own a heap pointer more idiomatic?

Tags: rust

I have a type that occupies too much space to be allocated on the stack:

```
struct Foo {
    lots_of_bytes: [u8; 1024 * 10],
    bar: bool,
    baz: isize,
}
```

There are two obvious solutions:

```
let foo = Box::new(Foo::new());
```

**Or**

```
struct Foo {
    lots_of_bytes: Box<[u8; 1024 * 10]>,
    bar: bool,
    baz: isize,
}
```

To summarize, I either allocate the entire struct on the heap, or I can have the struct own the heap pointer. Is either of these solutions considered the "idiomatic" solution? Or is it strictly subjective or dependent on context?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the question to ask yourself here is: *will it ever make sense to place this struct in the stack?* If the answer is no, you should probably enforce allocation on the heap. To achieve this, you have two alternatives:

1. Use `lots_of_bytes: Box<[u8; 1024 * 10]>`.
2. Use `lots_of_bytes: [u8; 1024 * 10]` and ensure that all constructors of `Foo` return `Box<Foo` (so it becomes impossible to create a `Foo` on the stack).

In my opinion, the first alternative is much better:

- The struct definition of `Foo` shows clearly that the data must be stored on the heap.
- This only requires boxing `lots_of_bytes`, instead of the whole struct. This means that `bar` and `baz` would be placed on the stack, so you have less indirection.

As for the second alternative, I can't think of any reason to prefer it and have never seen it in the wild.

Comment: Your first paragraph is slightly unclear; it could apply to both having `Foo::new` returns a `Box<Foo>` and `Foo` containing a `Box`. From the second paragraph I guess you aimed for the latter, which is also what I would advise in this case, but it would be clearer if the first paragraph could be understood by itself.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I wrote the answer in a hurry, and it shows. Let me know if the edited version is clear enough.

Comment: Question -- how can you enforce that nobody can create Foo on the stack (in your 2nd scenario?)  Can't you always create something on the stack with the `let stack_foo = Foo { }` syntax?

Comment: Only if the fields are public. Here, you would make the fields private and only expose constructor functions that return `Box<Foo>`. You would still be able to create `Foo` on the stack within the module where `Foo` itself is defined, but anyone using the API from the outside would be unable to do so.

Comment: See [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=mod%20foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20struct%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20u32%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20use%20foo%3A%3AFoo%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Foo%20%7B%20bar%3A%2042%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D&version=stable&backtrace=0) for an example.

Comment: @aochagavia Aahhhh I see -- I didn't know member visibility could differ from struct visibility...thanks man!